# In Android - how can I fill a view or drawing by a specific percantage?

Tags: android-layout, android

How can I fill a bitmap in Android with a specific background, with only a percentage of it being covered, like below?

There would be a icon in the middle as well so the fill would have to be behind what is drawn. I tried using a gradient, but it wasn't fruitful.

[image: half circle]

---

Edit: Another image:

[image]

Assuming the Processing 67% is a textview and the green is the background that fills 67% of that Textview, how would you accomplish this in Android?

Comment: This link might be of some help for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858531/filling-a-circle-gradually-from-bottom-to-top-android/24866667?noredirect=1#comment38644747_24866667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Arc here is the reference [Arc Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float%29)
and here is a great tutorial that might be of help to you: [How to draw semicircle on Android Canvas](http://blog.mwrobel.eu/howt-draw-semicircle-android-canvasenhow-draw-semicircle-android-canvas/).

other than that, would require a bit more of your code to help you out.

Comment: Sorry you may have misunderstood, I don't want to draw half circles, I want to fill an existing view (TextView, ImageView, etc) with a background colour to a certain percentage. See updated image please.

Comment: you still do it with the method i mentioned, you just have to be updating your view and setting the new xStart,yStart and xEnd, yEnd. and on that way you would be filling your view.