# filling a circle gradually from bottom to top android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-shape

I have created a circle with a stroke and white background using xml. How can this be filled gradually from bottom to top on user actions(e.g. on successive button press)?[image]

Is there any free library which can be used to achieve similar thing?

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11918728/1777090) gives any clue

Comment: The example is more of everything programmatic, not from xml. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I created a Custom View class that will do what you want. There are four custom attributes that can be set in your layout xml:

- `fillColor`, *color* - Sets the color of the fill area. Default is `Color.WHITE`.
- `strokeColor`, *color* - Sets the color of the bounding circle. Default is `Color.BLACK`.
- `strokeWidth`, *float* - Sets the thickness of the bounding circle. Default is `1.0`.
- `value`, *integer: 0-100* - Sets the value for the fill area. Default is `0`.

Please note that these attributes must have the `custom` prefix in lieu of the `android` prefix in your layout xml. The root `View` should also contain the `custom` xml namespace. *(See the example below.)* The other standard `View` attributes - such as `layout_width`, `background`, etc. - are available.

First, the `CircleFillView` class:

```
public class CircleFillView extends View
{
    public static final int MIN_VALUE = 0;
    public static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;

    private PointF center = new PointF();
    private RectF circleRect = new RectF();
    private Path segment = new Path();  
    private Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
    private Paint fillPaint = new Paint();

    private int radius;

    private int fillColor;
    private int strokeColor;
    private float strokeWidth;
    private int value;

    public CircleFillView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CircleFillView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.CircleFillView,
            0, 0);

        try
        {
            fillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleFillView_fillColor, Color.WHITE);
            strokeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleFillView_strokeColor, Color.BLACK);
            strokeWidth = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CircleFillView_strokeWidth, 1f);
            value = a.getInteger(R.styleable.CircleFillView_value, 0);
            adjustValue(value);
        }
        finally
        {
            a.recycle();
        }   

        fillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
        strokePaint.setColor(strokeColor);
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    public void setFillColor(int fillColor)
    {
        this.fillColor = fillColor;
        fillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getFillColor()
    {
        return fillColor;
    }

    public void setStrokeColor(int strokeColor)
    {
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
        strokePaint.setColor(strokeColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getStrokeColor()
    {
        return strokeColor;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth)
    {
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getStrokeWidth()
    {
        return strokeWidth;
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        adjustValue(value);
        setPaths();

        invalidate();
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    private void adjustValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = Math.min(MAX_VALUE, Math.max(MIN_VALUE, value));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        center.x = getWidth() / 2;
        center.y = getHeight() / 2;
        radius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2 - (int) strokeWidth;
        circleRect.set(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, center.x + radius, center.y + radius);

        setPaths();
    }

    private void setPaths()
    {
        float y = center.y + radius - (2 * radius * value / 100 - 1);
        float x = center.x - (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(y - center.y, 2));

        float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((center.y - y) / (x - center.x)));
        float startAngle = 180 - angle;
        float sweepAngle = 2 * angle - 180;

        segment.rewind();
        segment.addArc(circleRect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
        segment.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawPath(segment, fillPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, strokePaint);
    }
}
```

Now, for the custom xml attributes to work, you will need to put the following file in the `/res/values` folder of your project.

`attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CircleFillView" >
        <attr name="fillColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="strokeColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="strokeWidth" format="float" />
        <attr name="value" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Following are the files for a simple demonstration app, where the `CircleFillView`'s value is controlled with a `SeekBar`.

The layout file for our `Activity`, `main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.circlefill"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.circlefill.CircleFillView
        android:id="@+id/circleFillView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        custom:fillColor="#6bcae2"
        custom:strokeColor="#75b0d0"
        custom:strokeWidth="20"
        custom:value="65" />

    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And, the `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    CircleFillView circleFill;
    SeekBar seekBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        circleFill = (CircleFillView) findViewById(R.id.circleFillView);

        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setProgress(circleFill.getValue());
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                {
                    if (fromUser)
                        circleFill.setValue(progress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
            }
        );
    }   
}
```

And a screenshot of the demo app:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have given up vote for your code. However, I need support for Jelly bean and above.

Comment: Good solution Mike. Any idea how it would be done if it was an image instead of a circle?

Comment: Tested and working fine with versions: 2.2, 2.3.4, 4.2.2, 4.4.4. Thank you very much @MikeM. for the simple and clear solution.

Comment: How can I port this answer to fill a heart shaped Canvas, I mainly use Path to it so there is no circle or any pre-defined shapes ? Any ideas ?

Comment: If someone needs to change background filling color (the part of the circle that is not blue) you just need to swap the order of draw path and drawCircle and pass some color to paint of drawCircle

Comment: @2943 The [first few revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24866667/revisions) of my answer show a method that can be used with an arbitrary `Path`. As noted, though, it's only good for API >= 19. Prior to that, you could possibly use `Canvas#clipPath()`, but there are some issues with that method and hardware acceleration in older versions that you'd need to consider.

Comment: Great solution! I love it! Is it possible to fill the circle with a gradient effect?

Comment: @user2529173 Sure, shouldn't be too complicated, I would think. For example, you could [set a `LinearGradient` shader](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8600845) on the `fillPaint` object. You'd want to do that in the `onSizeChanged()` method, though, instead of in the constructor, so you have correct x,y values. Off the cuff, try something like `fillPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, center.y + radius, 0, center.y - radius, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP))` at the end of that method. Should give you an idea of how to proceed.